# Closing credits for Brave: subtle nods towards Tangled and Frozen?

Tags: disney, frozen, brave, crossovers, tangled

[The Frozen Theory](https://joshubuh.com/2014/03/24/thefrozentheory/) is fascinating, and very interesting, but this question is not about that.

Anyway, in the *Brave* end credits there seems to be quite a few six-pointed sun symbols shown in the background which bear a striking resemblance to the emblem of the Kingdom of Corona (the setting of *Tangled*). Also in the *Brave* credits are quite a few snowflakes, which seemed like maybe a reference to *Frozen*, which makes extensive use of snowflake visuals.

[image: Tangled sun emblem]
[image: Frozen snowflake]
<sup>(Above images are from *Tangled* and *Frozen*; not from *Brave*.)</sup>

The appearance of the snowflakes could possibly be explained by the fact that *Brave* is set in Scotland, and the [film was originally planned to contain a lot more snow than it eventually did](http://disneyaddict.tumblr.com/post/26424941803/i-have-mentioned-before-that-there-were-a-lot-of). But it seems more than that to me. Does anybody know if they are deliberate nods towards the (at the time) most recently released, and next planned Disney princess films?

**UPDATE:** The plot thickens. I was just re-watching *Tangled* (my kids are obsessed with it at the moment, so I get to watch it several times a week) and noticed something in the end credits for that film too. The credits (which can be [seen on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_x8VQePIWKU)) include various scenes from the film such as Flynn ascending Rapunzel's tower, "Wanted" posters, the man with the hook playing piano in the Snuggly Duckling, Flynn being chased by a bear, a map of the Kingdom... wait a minute... back up a bit... **Flynn being chased by a bear?!** There are no bears in *Tangled*, so what's with the bear in the credits?! A forward reference to *Brave*?

Comment: Disney loves putting Easter eggs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found no references about this anywhere online, so I'm going to say **no**, they are not (deliberate) references. There are plenty of Easter Eggs that Disney, and Pixar in particular, are famous for. For an example of these, see [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Pixar_film_references).

However, no member of the production team for any of these films has made any comment about observations like yours, so it seems likely there are coincidence.

I would also add that because you *want* to believe this so much, you *will* find more evidence in support of it than there perhaps really is. That's not to suggest you're wrong or that these scenes in the movies can't be interpreted this way - just that, based on all the evidence available, it seems *unlikely* they are intentional nods to other Disney films.